# magento simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php, magento

Estava adicionando produtos em minha loja normalmente até que as imagens pararam de aparecer no front e quando fui ver o log de erro o que apareceu foi:

```
2015-10-28T11:40:00+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found  in /home/espacoor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
2015-10-28T11:40:00+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot;?&gt;  in /home/espacoor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
2015-10-28T11:40:00+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                      ^  in /home/espacoor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
```

Abaixo o código ao arquivo entre a linha 430 á 451

```
// custom local layout updates file - load always last
    $updateFiles[] = 'local.xml';
    $layoutStr = '';
    foreach ($updateFiles as $file) {
        $filename = $design->getLayoutFilename($file, array(
            '_area'    => $area,
            '_package' => $package,
            '_theme'   => $theme
        ));
        if (!is_readable($filename)) {
            continue;
        }
        $fileStr = file_get_contents($filename);
        $fileStr = str_replace($this->_subst['from'], $this->_subst['to'], $fileStr);
        $fileXml = simplexml_load_string($fileStr, $elementClass); //Linha 444
        if (!$fileXml instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
            continue;
        }
        $layoutStr .= $fileXml->innerXml();
    }
    $layoutXml = simplexml_load_string('<layouts>'.$layoutStr.'</layouts>', $elementClass);
    return $layoutXml;
```

Alguém tem ideia do porque isso aparecer assim do nada?

--

Consegui encontrar o erro usando o seguinte código;
`Mage::Log($filename, true);`
logo após o

```
if (!is_readable($filename)) {
   continue;
}
```

Fazendo isso todos os arquivos que foram abertos foram registrador no `system.log`.
Notei que logo apos um modulo `ipgbasegratis.xml` e `ipgpagsegurogratis.xml` serem chamado o erro aparecia...exatamente no arquivo `ipgpagsegurogratis.xml`.

```
Erro no processamento de XML: nenhum elemento encontrado
Posição: file:///tmp/fz3temp-1/ipgpagsegurogratis.xml

Número da linha 1, coluna 22:<?xml version="1.0"?>
                             ---------------------^
```

Este arquivo é responsavel por exibir o modo de pagamento no final da compra, o que mais deveria conter apos este trecho do xml? notem que o erro esta apontando para as aspas duplas quando é exibido no log de erros.

Comment: por algum motivo ele esta convertendo os caracteres "<" por "&lt;" que é como se usaria para o html não interpretar como uma TAG. Oque tem no local.xml ? pode postar o conteúdo?

Comment: Hiago, voce se refere ao local.xml do tema?

Comment: Isso ai geralmente acontece quando o xml não está bem formatado.

Comment: @rray eu acho que encontrei o erro, coloquei `Mage::Log($filename, true)`para listar os arquivos no log e quando apareceu o erro vi que foi depois do arquivo `ipgpagsegurogratis.xml` e quando abro ele aparece o erro em questão que está "faltando" algum caracter porem o mesmo esta correto ao meu ver, o que contem nele é:  <?xml version="1.0"?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quanto ao erro pode estar ocorrendo por conta do arquivo não ter conteúdo somente a declaração do xml, tente colocar:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default></default>
</layout>
```